# Returning multiple combinations of rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table something like this

```
Col
1
2
3
4
```

I want to create all possible unique combinations
i.e. output table will be something like this

```
1,2
1,2,3
1,2,3,4
1,3
1,3,4
1,4
2,3
2,3,4
2,4
3,4
```

I tried doing this with join

```
SELECT T1.Col, T2.Col
FROM Table1 T1
JOIN Table1 T2
ON T1.Col < T2.Col
```

But this gives combination of 2 columns only.

Here I have taken example of 4 rows but table can have more or less rows as well.

Comment: You need a recursive cte to handle arbitrary number of values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a recursive CTE to generate this output:

```
declare @t table (Col int not null)
insert into @t(Col) values
(1),
(2),
(3),
(4);

with Items as (
    select Col, CONVERT(varchar(max), Col) as Concat from @t
    union all
    select t.Col, i.Concat + ',' + CONVERT(varchar(max),t.Col)
    from @t t
    inner join
    Items i on t.Col > i.Col
)
select Concat from Items
```

Results:

```
1
2
3
4
3,4
2,3
2,4
2,3,4
1,2
1,3
1,4
1,3,4
1,2,3
1,2,4
1,2,3,4
```

Or, to exclude the root items (only one element) add an additional column to count the "level" of recursion:

```
with Items as (
    select Col, CONVERT(varchar(max), Col) as Concat, 1 as Level from @t
    union all
    select t.Col, i.Concat + ',' + CONVERT(varchar(max),t.Col), Level + 1
    from @t t
    inner join
    Items i on t.Col > i.Col
)
select Concat from Items
where Level > 1
```

Results:

```
3,4
2,3
2,4
2,3,4
1,2
1,3
1,4
1,3,4
1,2,3
1,2,4
1,2,3,4
```